# A bit unsual way to change look of a custom ContentControl

Tags: wpf

I might be just missing something or probably today is not my day but what I am trying to do keeps failing.

I have a custom control called MyContentControl. It looks like this:

```
public class MyContentControl : ContentControl
{
    static MyContentControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyContentControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyContentControl)));
    }

    public DockPanel DifferentLook
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Txt
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.DifferentLook != null)
        {
            this.Content = this.DifferentLook;
        }

        Binding b = new Binding("Txt");
        b.Source = this;
        this.SetBinding(ContentProperty, b);
        base.OnInitialized(e);
    }
}
```

This is its theme:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyContentControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is MainWindow:

```
<local:MyContentControl Txt="texty text">
    <local:MyContentControl.DifferentLook>
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Content = " DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
            <ContentPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </local:MyContentControl.DifferentLook>
</local:MyContentControl>
```

When no "DifferentLook" specified I would like the control to use the ContentPresenter defined inside the default ControlTemplate.

If I have DifferentLook set then it should display the control in different look.

See the method OnInitalized.

Now the problem is when I apply DifferentLook it seems that the DifferentLook.ContentPresenter is not working.

Why is DifferentLook.ContentPresenter not appyling the content correctly?

The output on window is "texty text" but it should be "content = texty text".

**EDIT:** This is the light version. I created this and kept things as simple as possible to demostrate the problem. In real the custom control is a bit huge and user may not override ControlTemlates.

Do you guys have an idea how to solve this with the given requirements?

Comment: I don't understand why you're going to all that trouble. In WPF, if a user of a control wants to make that control look different, they just replace the default `ControlTemplate`... it seems as if you are trying to 're-invent the wheel'.

Comment: @Sheridian No re-inventing the wheel. This is the light version. I created this and kept things as simple as possible to demo the problem. In real the control is huge and user may not override controltemlate. Do you have an idea how to solve this with the given requirements?

Comment: You must have cut out too much for your example because I can't get it to work at all on my computer.

Comment: It works for me.  What error do you get? I ll take a look again on the code I posted. I might have misspelled myself somewhere. :)

Comment: No errors, but just an empty `Window`. Where did you define your `Style`? I tried adding it to the `Resources` section of the `ContentControl`, `MainWindow` and even in `Generic.xaml`.

Comment: I placed the code of generic.xaml in the question. Its just a border with contentpresenter. The result I wish to get is "content=texy text" the result I get is "texy text". The control doesnt take DockPanel and its content. Though I wish it to take them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddy I am not quite agreed with the approach you are taking here. But I can point out what you are doing wrong and why you are not able to see your `DockPanel`.

Since you have defined the `ControlTemplate` for your `ContentControl` having `ContentPresenter`, then any `Content` you set on your `ContentControl` will be placed inside the ContentPresenter of your `ControlTemplate` defined in style whether it is the `Content` set by `Binding` or Directly placed inside on control (like `DockPanel` here)

In your example, `OnInitialized()` function first set the `Content` to the `DockPanel` and then immediatly set `Binding` on `Content`. The moment Binding is set it will override the previously set `DockPanel` with the `Source` value which is `string` Txt(texty text).

So if you remove the `Binding` setting from `Oninitialized` you will see your `DockPanel`. But wait there is one more thing. Inside the `Content` of your `ContentPresenter` with `Content` bound as `Content="{Binding}"` which will make your programme to go into infinite recursion as it will try to bind it to self and on and on. So you will have to set the `Content` `Binding` of inner `ContentPresenter` to some property of Parent ContentControl Context. So just for testing try removing the content binding from inner contentpresenter and give some static value.

Comment: Ahh thanks man. But I have no idea why I am stuck with this. Its not my day today :) Yea I realized now too that I was overriding content with the Binding. I removed now the Content="{Binding}" away from the DifferentLook.ContentPresenter. Still how can I make this work? DifferentLook shall be used and Content should be displayed with DifferentLook.ContentPresenter. Any ideas?